# Adding an Object to multiple lists/maps

Tags: java, object, arraylist

```
ArrayList<SomeObject> listSomeObject;
HashMap<String, SomeObject> hmSomeObject;

SomeObject so = new SomeObject();
listSomeObject.add(so);
hmSomeObject.put("key", so);

hmSomeObject.get("key").setSomeProp(5);
```

Would that set operation at the end change the ArrayList's element as well; is there really actually just one object? In other words:

```
listSomeObject.get(0).getSomeProp()
```

Would this return 5?

Comment: Run it, and, test it?

Comment: I don't want to run it; I want to see the answer right away when I google it. So these guys made the sacrifice of saying yes and putting an indexed page about this, little issue. Your neighbour might need it one day

Comment: I would expect my neighbour to spend some time reading some good Java book, or online tutorial, to understand the concept, rather than looking on google for such things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Long answer: yes!

Really long answer: Why didn't you try it out and find out that it is indeed returning 5?

Comment: I guessed it would be yes; and I could try it but when I googled it I couldn't see any result right away; so I wanted this to be also sort of on the record.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one object named `so`, which is referred (referenced) by map and list. So any change done on `so` via any reference is visible everywhere.

So answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This because so is a reference to a value, not the value itself. Whether you put the reference in a list, map, or something else, you will still be modifying the same value.

Comment: Cheers, just fixed it.